# What is this red liquid produced by a fungal colony?

Tags: mycology, antibiotics, experiment

In a jar, where I had some orchid plants, a fungi start growing few days ago. I removed the plants and let the fungi to expand and grow more.  After some days, red drops started to appear on the surface of the fungal body (images below).

Does anyone know what this probably can be or recognize the fungi? Is it an antibiotic or something else?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take this with a massive pinch of salt (which is why I'm posting it as a comment) but I guess the reason the colonies have turned red is that the fungi processes Fe(III) so perhaps this review might shed some light as to what it is you are looking at (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC100245/).